# Angular 4 / ngx-bootstrap BsModalService with Dynamic Injection

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

i'm using [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/) with Angular 4 specific a ModalModule.

Scenario:
I have three component *Child* extend from a Component *Parent*.

I'll try to inject `BsModalService` in the parent component using the constructor, but i received and Error message `super()` because is missing the `BsModalService` parameter.

How i cal solve it?

I tried to use `ReflectiveInjector` or the new `StaticInjector` or a simple new BsModalService but i could not figure out, how to get and pass the parameter `ComponentLoaderFactory`

Please, i need your help

Comment: did u import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap'; in Module.ts file ?

Comment: Yes ModalModule.forRoot() in the Application Module, not in the module where is the Parent

Comment: can you provide source code? at least class declarations with @annotation and constructors?

Comment: Still looking for a better solution,  i could not found the way to extend the parent, so use a 3rd. component as helper. I do not think is a best practice, so is not worthy to share the code at this time.